# QuickFix Sequence Reset not working

Tags: numbers, sequence, reset, matching, quickfix

I am working on QuickFix/J (FIX 4.2)to submit orders to an acceptor FIX engine. Basically I need help on two accounts:

1. When I first try to establish a connection with the acceptor, the acceptor rejects the initial Logon requests saying "Msg Seq No too Low". After this my initiator goes on incrementing the outgoing sequence number by one and when this seq no. and the no. expected by the acceptor engine match, I get a stable connection. To speed this process, I began to extract the expected seq. no. from the reject message sent by the acceptor engine and changed the outgoing sequence no. for my engine using

   ```
   session.setNextTargetMsgSeqNum(expectedSeqNo).
   ```

   However, later on, if my engine finds incoming sequence no. higher than expected, it sends a Resend request. In response, the other party sends back a Sequence Reset msg (35=4, 123=Y). Now after receiving this msg, incoming seq no. for my engine should be automatically set to the one it received from Seq Reset msg. But this does not happen and my engine goes on asking for messages resend request with no change in the incoming seq no.
   Interesting thing is, I found this thing to work when I don't explicitly change the outgoing seq no in the first place (using  setNextTargetMsgSeqNum).

   Why is my engine not showing expected behavior when it gets Sequence Reset Msg?
2. I have talked to the other party and they won't have ResetOnLogon=Y in their configuration. So every time my engine comes up, it often sends Logon request with a seq no. lower than expected(starts from 1). Is there a better way to have the connection set up quickly? Like can I somehow make my engine use the sequence no. resuming from the point just before it went down? What should be the ideal approach?

So I am now persisting the messages in a file which is taking care of sequence numbers. However, what is troubling again is, my quickfix initiator engine is not responding to Sequence Reset messages. There are no admin call backs at all now.

I notice that no response to sequence reset message is happening almost always when I am connecting to the acceptor from one server and then, closing that session, and using a different server to connect to the acceptor, using the same session id. Once the logon is accepted, I expect things to work fine. However, while the other engine sends sequence reset to a particular number (gap fill basically), my fix engine does not respond to it, meaning, it does not reset its expected sequence number and keeps on sending resend requests to the acceptor. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

For normal FIX session usage, you configure the session start and end times and let the engine manage the sequence numbers. For example, if your session is active from 8:00 AM to 4:30 PM then QuickFIX/J will automatically reset the outgoing and incoming sequence number to 1 the first time the engine is started after 8:00 AM (or at 8:00 AM if the engine is already started at that time).

(Question #1). You are correct that your engine should use the new incoming sequence number after the Sequence Reset. Given that this works properly for thousands of QuickFIX/J users, think about what you might be doing that would change that behavior. For example, do you have an admin message callback and might it be throwing exceptions. Have you looked at your log files to see if there are any hints there?

(Question #2). If you are using a persistent MessageStore (FileStore, JdbcStore, etc.) then your outgoing sequence number will be available when you restart.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Your reply did help a lot. There was indeed a callback exception! And your direction for persistent MessageStore is helpful too.

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear it helped. Are you going to accept the answer? :-)

Comment: Unaccepting an accepted answer is not an effective way to get additional help. It would have been better to start a new question.